# Formula that uses IF statements not working

Tags: formula, formula-field, campaign-member, report-formula

I am trying to use a formula field on the Campaign Member object to pull from either a Lead or Contact.  The Formula Text field works but the Formula Number field does not, and I am not sure why.

So On the Contact record I have a score of 65, but when I run a report with Campaign Members, the score shows 3.

Report Type: Campaign with Campaign Members.

```
IF( NOT(ISBLANK(Lead.Lead_Score__c)) , Lead.Lead_Score__c , 

IF( NOT(ISBLANK(Contact.Lead_Score__c)) , Contact.Lead_Score__c , 

3))
```

Comment: What are the types of fields `Lead_Score__c` on contact and lead?

Comment: They are both Number(10, 0)

Comment: Try just comparing to null instead of checking `ISBLANK`. So use `IF(Lead.Lead_Score__c != null, ..., ...)`.

Comment: I used the NOT(ISNULL())  that works.   Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
IF( NOT(ISNULL(Lead.Lead_Score__c)) , Lead.Lead_Score__c , 

IF( NOT(ISNULL(Contact.Lead_Score__c)) , Contact.Lead_Score__c , 

3))
```